# How to view data easily by client and by assignment in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I own a digital marketing agency and I started using Google Sheets as my project management tool. I have multiple clients that I work with.

So I have created a Google Sheet for all my project management and created multiple sheets for each client. But this is a little bit painful for my team as they have to go through each sheet to know what their tasks for today are.

So what I am planning to do is create 1 common sheet where all their tasks will auto populate, so all my team can just go into that one sheet and see what their tasks are. But I as a founder would like to use each sheet for each client as it's easy for me to plan ahead.

So is there anyway I could auto populate all this data into one sheet, meaning everytime I add a task in any of my client's sheet, that particular row/task will need to be automatically added into the common sheet that my team uses, so it's easy for me and for them. I am also attaching a screenshot of how a sheet would look within our business.

[image: Project management google sheet]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution would indeed to move *all* the data in *one and the same* tab. You can do that by copying and pasting the data to a new sheet and deleting the original sheets.

When you have everything in the same tab, you can use [filter views](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681) to decide which rows to show at a time. Filter views are different from regular filters and let multiple simultaneous users sort, filter and edit the sheet without disturbing each other.

To let the team see all tasks assigned to them across all clients, use the **Assigned To** column to filter by employee. To see all tasks related to a particular client, regardless of who it is assigned to, use the **Client** column to filter by client. You can also create combination filters with more complex criteria.

For additional ease of use, insert links in the frozen section of the sheet to easily switch between filter views, instead of having to go to **Data > Filter views** to switch. See the [Filter views example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ME5b4J6fQa8RRainxGtQkwTKFCg96N8_k6kCe8ABNyk/edit#gid=2048818001&fvid=336145647) spreadsheet for an illustration.

Comment: Hello @doubleunary, thanks so much for your prompt response. This is definitely a workaround, however, if we had like 10 clients, going through each client's sheet and finding the tasks might get a little tedious process. So it'd be a lot easier for my team to have all of these on one sheet so it'll be easy for me and for them to view and track their tasks everyday. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: Edited the answer to clarify that "one sheet" means "one tab". Your 10 clients would all go to the same tab. No more jumping from tab to tab or spreadsheet to spreadsheet.

Comment: Gotcha!! That makes sense and that should work actually. Thanks heaps for your help!! Much appreciated.

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)